# цикл if работает только если в нем есть alert

Tags: javascript, html, css

Цикл if работает только если в нем есть alert..как только удаляю alert("LoL") перестает работать,ето моя ошыбка или же баг? функция перезаписывает на калькуляторе знак операции

```
function changeAction(value)
{   

    var input = document.getElementById("t");


    if (input.value.length == 2)
    {   
        alert("LoL");
        if (input.value =='++' || input.value == '-+' || input.value =='/+' || input.value =='*+')
        {
            input.value = '+';
        }

        if (input.value =='--' || input.value == '/-' || input.value =='*-' || input.value =='+-')
        {
            input.value = '-';
        }

        if (input.value =='-*' || input.value == '/*' || input.value =='**' || input.value =='+*')
        {
            input.value = '*';
        }

        if (input.value =='//' || input.value == '*/' || input.value =='*-/' || input.value =='+/')
        {
            input.value = '/';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `if` это не цикл, откуда предположение, что перестает работать? как именно не работает? как вызывается changeAction?

Comment: В общем-то, весь этот `if` можно заменить каким-то таким: `if (input.value) input.value = input.value.charAr(input.value.length - 1);`

Comment: @Yaant, вы не правы, да и опечатка в названии функции, которую уже можно не использовать так как в строках уже давно можно обращаться  к символам по индексу `input.value[index]`

Comment: `input.value =='*-/'` - тут длина не 2.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых `if` является условным оператором, а не циклом.
Во-вторых `alert` всего лишь приостановаливает исполнение, но он не оказывает влияния на работу данного кода.

Попробуйте поискать ошибку воспользовавшись дебаггером (F12).

Comment: А уж если использовать ключевое слово `debugger` для установки брякпоинтов, то отладка станет ещё проще.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов, `debugger` - меняет код, и чтобы сделать его условным - нужно опять же менять код

Comment: @Grundy речь лишь о методе остановки. Любой уважающий себя javascript-движок встретив ключевое слово debugger остановит выполнение, если активен отладчик.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов, чтобы он его встретил, его надо прописать **в коде**, а это значит изменить исходный код. Если нужна _условная_ точка остановки, добавляется еще строка с условием, еще больше изменений исходного кода